# Python Parsing - Multiple Emails in One Text File

Tags: python, regex, xlwt

I receive similar emails from multiple senders and use regular expressions `m` and `n` below to pull out needed strings. That part is working fine.

Regular expression `o` however is what has me confused. The text file I am reading is a combination of 9 email messages saved to one text file and opened in Python as a string. Original Sender (regex `o`) occurs at the beginning of each new message in the file (9 times)

I want to write the same Original Sender after each CUSIP and NAME found until a different Original Sender is matched.

I am using xlwt3 and wincom32.

Sample from the text file with combined emails which is very standard:

```
--- Original Sender: TOM MADEUPNAME, SOME BANK, N. ---
----- Original Message -----
From: TOM MADEUPNAME (SOME BANK, N.)
To: BOB THISISMYEMAIL (XYZ INVESTMENTS, INC)
At:  8/31  8:53:25
**Offerings**

Mezz ReRemics
Cusip      Description       Original Current Cashflow Collat Offering
05531UAB6  BCAP 2009-RR5 1A2   18,745  18,745 Snr Sup  Fxd      45.000

Prime/Alt-A Fixed
Cusip      Description       Original Current Cashflow Collat Offering
059487AE8  BOAA 2006-6 CB5     25,940  14,350 Seq      Fxd      83.000
12544XAX3  CWHL 2007-9 A13     10,190  10,190 Ssnr Nas Fxd      92.500
17312XAJ3  CMSI 2007-4 1A9      2,871   2,741 Spr Snr  Fxd      86.000

--- Original Sender: JOE MADEUPNAME, EUROPEAN BANK SECURI ---
----- Original Message -----
From: JOE MADEUPNAME (EUROPEAN BANK SECURI)
To: BOB THISISMYEMAIL (XYZ INVESTMENTS, INC)
At:  8/31  8:20:16

8-31-2011 

Alt-A Fixed
Bond            O/F    C/F    Cpn  FICO CAL WALB  60+    Notes             Offer
CSMC 06-9 7A1   25.00  11.97  L+45  728  26  578  35.21  FLT,AS,0.0%       50-00
LXS 07-10H 2A1  68.26  34.01  L+16  744   6  125  33.98  SS,9.57%          42-00
CSMC 06-7 9A1   15.00   7.81  L+30  688   5  198  46.46  SS,0.0%           29-16

Prime Hybrid 
Bond            O/F     C/F   Cpn  FICO CAL WALB  60+    Notes             Offer
SARM 05-18 6A1  14.56   6.01  2.58  730  46  432  15.87  SEA,SS,5/1,12.3%  78-00

Alt-A Hybrid
Bond            O/F    C/F    Cpn  FICO CAL WALB  60+    Notes             Offer
ARMT 05-12 2A1  23.78  10.71  3.07  712  48  556  35.32  SS,5/1,4.9%       *SOLD

Option Arm
Bond                O/F    C/F   Cpn  FICO CAL WALB  60+    Notes          Offer
DBALT 07-OA4 1A1B  10.00   7.25  L+13  716  63  562  47.17  SS,OC,42.2%    64-16
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Updated - working

```
count_cusip = 0
count_name = 0
count_sender = 0 
cur_sender = ''
for line in lines:

    o = re.search(r"Original Sender:\s\b\w+\s\w+", line)
    if o:
        count_sender += 1
        ws.write(count_sender,2,o.group(0))
        ws.write(count_sender,2,cur_sender)
        cur_sender = o.group(0)

    m = re.search('[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}', line)
    if m:
        count_cusip += 1
        ws.write(count_cusip,0,m.group(0))
        ws.write(count_cusip,2,cur_sender)

    n = re.search('[A-Z]{3,5}\s[0-9]{1,4}\D{1,3}\S{1,3}\s{1,2}\w+', line)
    if n:
        count_name += 1
        ws.write(count_name,1,n.group(0))
        ws.write(count_cusip,2,cur_sender)

        o = re.search(r"Original Sender:\s\b\w+\s\w+", line)
        if o:
            cur_sender = o.group(0)

        ws.write(count_name,2,cur_sender)
```

### Updated Output - as desired.

```
CUSIP   Bond Name           Original Sender
00442PAD2   ACE 2006-OP1 A2B        Original Sender: Nick Madeupname
12557YAE7   ARMT 05-12 2A1          Original Sender: Bobby Madeupname
39153VAT1   CSMC 06-9 7A1           Original Sender: Bobby Madeupname
05377RAE4   LXS 07-10H 2A1          Original Sender: Jane Madeupname
02005HAF0   CSMC 06-7 9A1           Original Sender: Jane Madeupname
```

Comment: what is ws.write()?  Are you writing to a spreadsheet using `xlwt` or what?

Comment: it would help a great deal if you could post an example of the input you are trying to process.  You should change names, subject lines, and content of the emails to preserve privacy, but leave the general format intact so we can see what you are trying to parse.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `\b` in your last regex?  It seems to me you are looking for exactly one whitespace character after the colon, after which at least one alphanumeric must appear.  I would think this is, by definition, a word boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't completely clear since you didn't show an output sample, but here's an educated guess:

```
count_cusip = 0
count_name = 0
count_sender = 0 
cur_sender = ''
for line in lines:

    m = re.search('[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}', line)
    if m:
        count_cusip += 1
        ws.write(count_cusip,0,m.group(0))
        ws.write(count_cusip,2,cur_sender)

    n = re.search('[A-Z]{3,5}\s[0-9]{1,4}\D{1,3}\S{1,3}\s{1,2}\w+', line)
    if n:
        count_name += 1
        ws.write(count_name,1,n.group(0))
        ws.write(count_name,2,cur_sender)

    o = re.search(r"Original Sender:\s\b\w+\s\w+", line)
    if o:
        count_sender += 1
        cur_sender = o.group(0)
```

Rather than writing the Original Sender when encountered, you need to save it and write the current value for each cusip and name.

Comment: I posted the output to help. Seems this code produces an overwrite error.  Traceback (most recent call last):
     ws.write(count_sender,5,cur_sender)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\xlwt3\worksheet.py", line 961, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\xlwt3\row.py", line 226, in write
    StrCell(self.__idx, col, style_index, self.__parent_wb.add_str(label))
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\xlwt3\row.py", line 145, in insert_cell
    raise Exception(msg) Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname='Bond List' rowx=1 colx=5

Comment: Without knowing what ws.write does and the context in which you're running, it's not possible to figure out what you need to do.  The output you show clearly doesn't reflect what ws.write is doing.

Comment: ws.write comes from xlwt and writes to cells in excel. ws.write's format is (row,column,regex match). The for loop reads the text file line by line and the first pass for regex m matches a cusip in the string and writes that via ws.write(1,0,'929766LY7') to excel, as well regex n matches a bond_name and it is put to excel via ws.write(1,1,'WBMCMT 2003-C8 A4'). Am I helping?

Comment: @dadashek: OK, I updated the code to put the current original sender in column 3 on each line.  Your example still really doesn't make sense: why is Original Sender empty starting with FAIRF?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can change the format to something recognized by the [`mailbox`](http://docs.python.org/library/mailbox.html) module in the standard library.  Then you could let that module handle all the parsing.